# Qt: QList of QButtonGroup

Tags: c++, qt, linked-list

Hey! I try to do the following

```
    QList<QButtonGroup*> groups;
    for (int i=0; i<nGroup; i++)
    {
        QButtonGroup *objects = new QButtonGroup(this);
        objects->setExclusive(false);
        for (int j=0; j<nObject; j++)
        {
            Led *tempLed = new Led();
            tempLed->setAutoExclusive(false);
            layout->addWidget(tempLed,j,i,Qt::AlignLeft);
            objects->addButton(tempLed);
        }
        groups.append(objects);
    }
```

And then try to do something like this:

```
groups.at(1)->button(2)->setChecked(true);
```

The code compiles, but at runtime throws unhandled exception.
What am I doing wrong?
Any better way to create group of QButtonGroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QButtonGroup::button function returns the button for a specific ID, but you didn't use an id when you added the button to the buttongroup.  QButtonGroup::button returns 0 in your example leading to a null pointer access exception.

```
...
objects->addButton(tempLed);
...
```

If you change the code into

```
...
objects->addButton(tempLed, j );
...
```

you original code will work.

I prefer QList::at over QList::operator[] because you don't want to change the value (==pointer) in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related with the function [at](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlist.html#at). It returns a const item, and you are calling to a non-const function in it.

Use [operator[]](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d) instead.

Comment: Yes, I now use operator[] for both QList and QButtonGroup.
Thanks!

Comment: Be careful using the operator[] you can do mistakes and have unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it like this:

```
QButtonGroup *bG;
bG = groups[gr];
QAbstractButton *aB = bG->buttons()[obj];
aB->setChecked(command);
```

Didn't really get what was the problem thou.

Comment: Apparently button(2) was wrong, buttons()[2] was needed instead. Can't say more since I almost never use Qt.